# Does Makie have linked brushing capability similar to Holoviews?

Tags: julia, makie.jl

In [Holoviews](https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Linked_Brushing.html) it is possible to link two different plots, so that when we zoom in or select parts of one plot, the other plots reflects the same zooming in or selection. Are there similar functionality available in Makie?

**Edit 1**

Based on the answer I tried the code below, However, I get a static image. I tired it both in Jupyter lab notebook and VSCode both of which were installed in Windows Subsystem for Linux with Ubuntu. The code I tried is:

```
using CairoMakie

f = Figure(backgroundcolor = RGBf(0.98, 0.98, 0.98),
    resolution = (1000, 700)) 

ga = f[1, 1] = GridLayout()
gb = f[2, 1] = GridLayout()
gcd = f[1:2, 2] = GridLayout()
gc = gcd[1, 1] = GridLayout()
gd = gcd[2, 1] = GridLayout()

axtop = Axis(ga[1, 1])
axmain = Axis(ga[2, 1], xlabel = "before", ylabel = "after")
axright = Axis(ga[2, 2])

linkyaxes!(axmain, axright)
linkxaxes!(axmain, axtop)

labels = ["treatment", "placebo", "control"]
data = randn(3, 100, 2) .+ [1, 3, 5]

for (label, col) in zip(labels, eachslice(data, dims = 1))
    scatter!(axmain, col, label = label)
    density!(axtop, col[:, 1])
    density!(axright, col[:, 2], direction = :y)
end

f
```

**Edit 2**

After suggesting that I should use `GLMakie` for interactive plot, I tried it in VSCode and indeed I got an interactive plot. However, in Jupyter notebook, I got a static image. The solution is to use `Makie.inline!(false)` and `display(f)` rather than using `f`:

```
using GLMakie

Makie.inline!(false)

f = Figure(backgroundcolor = RGBf(0.98, 0.98, 0.98),
    resolution = (1000, 700)) 

ga = f[1, 1] = GridLayout()
gb = f[2, 1] = GridLayout()
gcd = f[1:2, 2] = GridLayout()
gc = gcd[1, 1] = GridLayout()
gd = gcd[2, 1] = GridLayout()

axtop = Axis(ga[1, 1])
axmain = Axis(ga[2, 1], xlabel = "before", ylabel = "after")
axright = Axis(ga[2, 2])

linkyaxes!(axmain, axright)
linkxaxes!(axmain, axtop)

labels = ["treatment", "placebo", "control"]
data = randn(3, 100, 2) .+ [1, 3, 5]

for (label, col) in zip(labels, eachslice(data, dims = 1))
    scatter!(axmain, col, label = label)
    density!(axtop, col[:, 1])
    density!(axright, col[:, 2], direction = :y)
end

display(f)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `linkxaxes!` and `linkyaxes!`. Here's an example: https://makie.juliaplots.org/v0.17.13/tutorials/layout-tutorial/index.html#panel_a

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you please confirm if you use the code I posted in my answer, you get a dynamic plot and when you zoom in or select part of the main plot, then the plots on side and top zoom or change in any way?

Comment: @MOON the Cairo backend isn't interactive - use GLMakie or WGLMakie instead

Comment: Still it is static. The plot in Jupyter lab notebook under Windows is inline, perhaps it is static because of that but I cannot find how to prevent inline plotting.

Comment: Under Windows and VSCode, I finally managed to plot an interactive plot and does what I asked thanks to your answer.